# R error on ANOVA of GLMs

Tags: r, glm, anova

I have a GLM that I am attempting to simplify like this:

```
MOD.3<-update(MOD.2, ~. -WIND.SPEED)
anova(MOD.2,MOD.3,test="Chi")
```

When I attempt to evaluate the models with:

```
anova(MOD.3,MOD.2)
```

I get the following error:

> Error in anova.glmlist(c(list(object), dotargs), dispersion = dispersion,  :
>
> models were not all fitted to the same size of dataset

I suspect this may have to do with the fact that I have missing values in the dataset, but I am not sure if this is the cause of the error nor how to approach it...

Comment: Yes, missing values are the cause of the error. Use `na.omit` to remove observations that have missing values in the subset of the data that is used in any of the models.